# Sorting by a non-key (arbitrary) field in CouchDB

Tags: sorting, couchdb

I have a fairly large CouchDB database (approximately 3 million documents). I have various view functions returning slices of the data that can't be modified (or at least, should only be modified as a last resort).

I need the ability to sort on an arbitrary field for reporting purposes. For smaller DBs, I return the entire object, `json_parse` it in our PHP backend, then sort there. However, we're often getting Out Of Memory errors when doing this on our largest DBs.

After some research, I'm leaning towards accessing a sort key (via URL parameter) in a [list function](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html) and doing the sort there. This is an idea I've stolen [from here](http://geekiriki.blogspot.ca/2010/08/couchdb-using-list-functions-to-sort.html). Excerpt:

```
function(head, req) {
  var row
  var rows=[]
  while(row = getRow()) {
    rows.push(row) 
  }
  rows.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.value-a.value
  })
  send(JSON.stringify({"rows" : rows}))
}
```

It seems to be working for smaller DBs, but it still needs a lot of work to be production ready.

Is this:

a) a good solution?
b) going to work with 3, 5, or 10 million rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid loading everything into memory by using a list function. So with enough data, eventually, you'll get an out of memory error, just as you're getting with PHP.

If you can live within the memory constrains, it's a reasonable solution, with some advantages.

Otherwise, investigate using something like lucene, elasticsearch, or Cloudant Search (clouseau & dreyfus).

Answer (score 0):

In our environment, we have more than 5 million records. The couch is design such that each and every Document has some specific fields which distinguish it from the other category of documents.

For example, there are number documents with field DocumentType "USer" or DocumentType "XXX"

These DocumentType field allow us to sort various document based on different categories.
 So if you have 3 Million doc, and you have around 10 categories so each category will have about 300k Docs.

Now you can design system such that you always pass the DocId you need to be passed to Couch. In that way it will be faster.

so query can be like

```
function(doc) 
{ 
if(doc.DocumentType=== 'XXX' && doc._id) {emit(doc.FieldYouWant, doc._id)} 
}
```

This is how our backhand is designed in production.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question... It doesn't have anything to do with sorting. How would you then sort that by `doc.SomeOtherField`?

Comment: Get all the field in List in Webservice Layer and then Sort it. It will be faster  and have less strain on Couch